# Google app engine OR QUERY ids with Objectify

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Hello I am using objectify with google app engine.
I've seen that I can do something like this one

```
List<Car> cars = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year in", yearList).list();
```

Which achieves an OR QUERY result
However when I try to query by id (set as a Long type),
I get an exception and that only filtering by Long or String values is allowed.
More specific

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Id filter values must be Long or String
```

Is it possible to make an OR QUERY by id filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying multiple ids use ..

```
ofy().load().type(Car.class).ids(IDs);
```

... where IDs is a List of your ids.